# Skiplagged with international flights

Tags: international-travel, layovers, hidden-city-ticketing

Skiplagged's website makes it seem like no big deal (i.e. just bring your passport and get off where you want). And of course you need to get a visa if either, or both, your final destination and "layover destination" require it.

But is it really that simple? Like domestic skiplagged?

I.E. If I want to go to Seoul and there is a cheap ticket that layovers in Seoul but final destination is actually Taiwan. Neither requires a visa so I would just get off in Seoul?

Has anyone actually done this? What was your experience?

Thanks.

DUPLICATE FLAG: I went to the link for the "duplicate"question, it doesn't really answer what I am looking for. That one is about hidden city travel and other airlines knowing; even if they did, which I'm sure they don't, I don't see why they'd care about what you did on another airline.

Comment: @Kuba: Not clear to me that it's a duplicate -- the question you link to seems to be specifically about hidden-city ticketing on a _round trip_ booking with two different carriers, which seems to be a rather more special case than _this_ question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm While the question may be not exactly the same, I think the answer there should answer this question beautifully (explaining concerns about visas, baggage etc). Let OP / someone else confirm as I might be wrong

Comment: What is skiplagged?

Comment: "Skiplagged's website makes it seem like no big deal" Makes _what_ seem like no big deal?

Comment: @DavidRicherby using hidden cities for international travel

Comment: @physlexic And where does your question say that?

Comment: By the way, it's annoying that the system claims that I marked the question as a duplicate. I did no such thing: I voted to close as unclear, on the exact point that I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it's in the title

Comment: @physlexic No it isn't. The title is "Skiplagged with international flights". That doesn't say what "it" means, since it clearly doesn't mean "Skiplagged" or "international flights".

Comment: @DavidRicherby skiplagged's platform is hidden city air travel.. if someone is unaware, I think anyone on here is more than open to explaining or clarifying.. stack forums are designed for free inquisition.. marking duplicates constrains answers to one local as opposed to disseminating them, going around and flagging for closure posts that are less than ideal is not conducive to the sharing of information.. in short, you're right it's not in the title.. congratulations

Comment: @physlexic As I said, I didn't vote to close as a duplicate. And questions put on hold for being unclear can always be reopened after they've been clarified. But the point of closing as duplicates is not to constrain answers but, rather, to ensure that good answers to questions aren't hidden because the same question has been asked multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on where you are going and your ticket.

If it is round trip, then all remaining legs will be canceled when you no show for the second flight.  Also no showing could inconvenience your fellow passengers if the airline delays the flight trying to find you (since they know you made it to Seoul).

Airlines provide API (Advance Passenger Information) to the governments of some countries and immigration officials have that data.  If your layover is in an API country and Immigration doesn't show you as an arriving passenger, your time at the Immigration counter could take a while.

For domestic flights, no showing is not a big deal unless you do it regularly.  But for international flights, the airline has more liability, since they are responsible for ascertaining that you have permission to enter the country.  And in your scenario, they would have only checked your eligibility for entering the final destination, not the layover country.  And while the government would in all likelihood not fine the airline since you bailed out without notice, your name could have a big red check mark next to it for future flights on that airline.

Comment: "your name could have a big red check mark next to it for future flights on that airline." - what does this mean? Ok, you have a red mark, so now what?

Comment: @JonathanReez - Would you prefer that I had used "red flag"?  OK, a red flag that you have a history of using hidden city tactics with that airline.

Comment: I'm simply asking to clarify what *practical* effects would having a "red mark/flag" have for a traveler.

Comment: This is the only thing I was thinking could happen. I was not sure if airlines send that information to immigration, because I have never been asked to show my boarding pass to any customs agent in any country. They just want my passport (and visa if needed) and customs paperwork.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any problem here, and make sure you go with just carry-on luggage :)

Also it seems that site is not really optimized for international and search with ITA Matrix could give better results.

Comment: I'm quite sure most of airlines don't allow hidden-city ticketing, so I don't think ITA Matrix should display such routes, as non conforming with airline regulations. And your first sentence is kinda unclear I think, first you say you don't see any problem, then you say to go only with your carry-on luggage (as registered luggage would be delivered to final destination).

Comment: @Kuba I think they track what you checked and who boards so checked luggage would be pulled off the plane where you got off, inconveniencing everyone. Otherwise someone could put something bad in their checked luggage and get off, leaving the luggage in the hold.

Comment: @Kuba Matrix won't display it automatically, you're right, but it can certainly be adapted to that purpose without difficulty. People who are quite familiar with Matrix tend to reach for it automatically to solve any itinerary problem, as it is the most powerful tool for the job.

Comment: @kuba traveling hidden city implies carry-on only, so Zack is suggesting just do what you normally would when using skiplagged